# Integer to Alphanumeric string conversion

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I need to convert five digit integer to alphanumeric string of length 5.Doing below but sometimes it doesn't provide alphanumeric but numeric value.

```
Long x = 12345L;
String code = Long.toHexString(x).toUpperCase();
```

I want to get Alphanumeric string of length 5 always.

Comment: What do you mean by "alphanumeric value"? You want to convert it to String?

Comment: Let say for Ex:-  12345 --> A12BC

Comment: What are the rules? Why 12345 turns into A12BC?

Comment: As such there are no rules,from client side i will generate some TOTP of five digit and then convert it to alphanumeric string of same length and then this data will travel through to backend,and on back end side similar TOTP logic will run and will again generate alphanumeric string. I am doing this just to encode this numeric value,i have space constraint because of vendor,only 5 character are permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hardly surprising.

For example, `0x12345` is `74565`, so `74565` does not contain any of the *digits* `A` to `F` when converted to hexadecimal.

Given that `99999` is `0x1869F`, you have plenty of room in your converted string to accommodate some "junk" data, consider introducing an additive constant (`0xA0000` perhaps which at least guarantees at least one alpha character for positive inputs), or even a number that your XOR with your original.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
static String alphaNumric(int value) {
    String s = "abcde" + Integer.toString(value, 36);
    return s.substring(s.length() - 5);
}
```

and

```
    int[] tests = { 12345, 1, 36, 36 * 36, 32767, 99999 };
    for (int i : tests)
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + alphaNumric(i));
```

output

```
12345 -> de9ix
1 -> bcde1
36 -> cde10
1296 -> de100
32767 -> depa7
99999 -> e255r
```